# Postgres hstore casting works wrong

Tags: java, postgresql, lambda, casting, hstore

The following line works incorrect with Java 8.
`(Map<Integer, BigDecimal>) resultSet.getObject("hstore_field");`

hstore key and value are stored as text in the Postgres DB. Despite the fact the object received from resultSet is casted to `Map<Integer, BigDecimal>` and no warnings/errors received during compilation time, data persisted in HashMap is of type `<String, String>`.
I have tested with instanceof BigDecimal and got false.
More interesting lambda way failed at runtime when doing

```
hstoreMap.foreach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + " " +v));
```

So,the problem is clear - casting does not work this way. Therefore I casted to Map and then converted map to required type.
Anyway, is this kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but here's what I was able to find for you:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4FAB8796.40904@nitorcreations.com

It looks like hstore support is still limited to `HashMap<String, String>`
wrapper object. I would not call it a bug anyway.